# For points $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ define $d(x,y)=|(x_{1}-y_{2})^{2}-(x_{2}-y_{1})^{2}|$. Does $d$ define a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

So I deduced that $d(x,y)$ is symmetric and reflexive fairly trivially, but I can not figure out how to prove whether or not $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\geq d(x,z)$ holds. I first tried to prove that it did not hold by plugging in random points, but then I did not know how to proceed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a metric space. In the "reflexivity" axiom, you need to check that $d(x,y)=0$ if **and only if** $x=y$. But here, $d((1,2), \, (2,1))=0$.

The triangle inequality is also false. Consider for example $x = (1,0)$, $y = (0,0)$ and $z = (2,2)$. Then $d(x,z) = 3$ where $d(x,y)+d(y,z) = 1+0 = 1$.

Comment: That makes sense. If you don't mind me asking, how did you think of that so quickly? 

Also, how would we prove whether or not the triangle inequality holds for this?

Comment: @MohammedShahid It's just experience. When I saw the formula I thought "well if $x_1 = y_2$ and $x_2 = y_1$ then this is zero". For the triangle inequality I know that $d((0,0),(n,n)) = 0$ for all $n$ so I just take another random point "far" from $(n,n)$ but "close" to $(0,0)$.